# Java e MySQL - Erro - Timezone

Tags: java, mysql, timezone

Tento conectar com o MySQL, com o código abaixo. Não uso Hibernate, nem nada. 
É só para conectar ao banco e executar uma cláusula SQL simples. Recebo o erro que está abaixo.

Já vi que tem algumas perguntas com respostas aqui, mas confesso que não entendi.

**Mensagem de erro:**

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora Padrão da Europa Ocident' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

**Código:**

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectMySql {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Estabelece a conexão
            Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mondovino", "root", "senha");

            // Cria um Statement
            Statement stmt = cnx.createStatement();

            // Executa a query
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("seletc * from paese"); 

            // Navega no result set
            while (rset.next()) {
                System.out.println("Pais " + rset.getString("fips") + " -> " + rset.getString("nomepaese"));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Eu adicionei isso na minha URL do BD e funcionou: ?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Answer (score 3):

Tente adicionar na sua url de conexão estes parâmetros: `useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC`

Ficará assim:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mondovino?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "senha");
```

Comment: Perfetto. Niente come parlare con chi sa cosa si deve fare. Certinho. Valeu.

Comment: @Alano, marque como correta a resposta. Assim indicará aos outros que a resposta está correta.